# How to pass JSON result into a global variable in JavaScript after calling the method using URL from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am trying to bring the Json result into a variable that is declared outside of the calling place.  A GET method is being called and I want the Json result to be stored in a variable `mapresult` declared globally. Here is the code:

```js
<script>
var mapresult;
function FillMappings(defaultSelected) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/User/GetDepotDepartemntsForMap",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                 mapresult = data // the value is coming as undefined
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.responseText);
            }

        });

    }
console.log(mapresult )
</script>
```

The Get method is given below.

```
public JsonResult GetDepotDepartemntsForMap() {
        dynamic mappingList = new List<DepotMapModel>();
        mappingList = _unitOfWork.Department.GetDepotWithDepartment();         
        return Json(mappingList);
}
```

The result of the GET method is given as array result as  below

```
Array(6)
0: 1.1
1: 1.2
2: 1.4
3: 2.1
4: 1
5: 2
Length: 6
```

How can I store the result from the GET method into the variable declared `mapresult`.

Comment: Hi @Alan Pauil, where did you see the array result that you shared? If you see the data in console panel, it is impossible comes undefined. Please explain more detailed.

Comment: if you want to store as a global variable in javascript you can use window.variable_name='value' and if you want to access even if the page refresh, you can use local storage or cookie.